# Correctly mapping directories

Tags: python, directory, formatting, syntax-error, nvidia

I am trying to get a training module on the transfer learning toolkit to run and cannot seem to map my directories correctly.  I omitted the equals sign that I had earlier between os.environ and path name. Still returns error.  I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

```
mport json
import os 
default_value = '~/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR'
os.getenv('LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR', default_value)
mounts_file = os.path.expanduser("~/.tlt_mounts.json")

# Define the dictionary with the mapped drives
drive_map = {
    "Mounts": [
        # Mapping the data directory
        {
            "source": os.environ["/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/data"],
            "destination": "/workspace/tlt-experiments"
        },
        # Mapping the specs directory.
        {
            "source": os.environ["/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/files"],
            "destination": os.environ["/workspace/tlt-experiments/specs"]
        },
    ]
}
```

Errors given:

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
11         # Mapping the data directory
12         {
---> 13             "source": os.environ["/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/data"],
14             "destination": "/workspace/tlt-experiments"
15         },

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/os.py in **getitem**(self, key)
673         except KeyError:
674             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 675             raise KeyError(key) from None
676         return self.decodevalue(value)
677

KeyError: '/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/data'

My code ran smoothly after this update:

```
# Define the dictionary with the mapped drives
drive_map = {
    "Mounts": [
        # Mapping the data directory
        {
            "source": "/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/data",
            "destination": "/workspace/tlt-experiments"
        },
        # Mapping the specs directory.
        {
            "source": "/LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR/files",
            "destination": "/workspace/tlt-experiments/specs"
        },
    ]
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Looks like line 11 needs to read `"source": os.environ["LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR"],`. Did you try that?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did. I've updated with the post with the new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**  Your new error is a result of an environment variable not existing.  In this case you should really use the below and set a default variable.

```
default_value = 'C:\Temp'
os.getenv('LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR', default_value)
```

Comment: I've updated my code and still have an error.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit strange because the error talk about a line that don't exist in the code you post. But try to replace `"source": os.environ="LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR"` by `"source": os.environ["LOCAL_PROJECT_DIR"]` at the line 11.